# Handling onMessageOpenedApp Callback in Flutter FCM When Returning to Foreground from Background

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my Flutter app. In the `firebase_messaging` package, I've set up `onBackgroundMessage` to display custom notifications when the app is in the background. However, the issue I'm facing is that when I tap the notification and the app comes back to the foreground, the `onMessageOpenedApp` callback is not triggered as I expect it to be. How can I handle this situation properly?

Comment: Where have you written the `onMessageOpenedApp` callback?